# How should I use control + delete or control + backspace to delete till underscore

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, data-science, jupyter, jupyter-lab

In Jupyter lab suppose I have a variable `string_text`
if I use `ctrl+backspace` the entire word is deleted is there a way to delete just the `text` part in the above example so I am just left with `string_`
It would be a helpful hack.
The same happens with `ctrl + delete` would be helpful If someone can point me to some resource. I am unable to find help or a hack to do this.

What happens:-
If i have `string_test_first_row` variable if I use `ctrl + backspace` the entire variable is deleted.

More Explanation:

Is it possible?
If I press `ctrl + backspace` I am left with `string_test_first_` (just the word after last underscore deleted)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using Vim extension solves this problem. vim extension can do many more things than this but needs some effort learning vim.Vim is a great way to be efficient and can help achieve multiple such simple editing problems

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you, you are trying to delete the word "text" from string_text so that you will be left with "String_"

Try this

Highlight the "text" and press delete or use the Backspace.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: I want a simple hack. I know about highlighting. is something I could do with modifiers such as ctrl or shift or alt or combination plus backspace? I have a lot of strings like them and I need to delete 1 or 2 words till underscore and not the entire thing

Comment: In that case you could use search-and-replace with regular expression in JupyterLab.

Comment: I could do that with code. I am looking for a simple hack just. This works in MS Word. ctrl backspace erases till underscore but here it deletes the entire thing which is not desired.